# liquibase diff without database server

Tags: hibernate, liquibase

Coming from Django/South database migrations, I'm used to being able to generate a new migration (change set) without needing the database server running: that tool compares the models to set of existing migrations to figure out what the next migration is.

I want to use Liquibase in the same way but it seems to require a database running.  I'm already set to use the hibernate extension for the referenceUrl (hibernate:classic:hibernate.cfg.xml), but I want it to compare the new JPA hibernate model classes against a set of existing change logs, rather than a database instance.

Is this at all possible?  Is there another alternative out there that works with Hibernate but behaves more like Django/South does?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot currently compare a hibernate configuration with a changelog script. It is something that can be implemented, but it has not been yet unfortunately.